# Limit the product description length in " Featured product" or" Recent product"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to limit the length of the product description.

```
function short_product_titles_chars( $title, $id ) {
    if (
        (is_shop() || is_product_tag() || is_product_category()) && 
        get_post_type($id) === 'product') 
    {
        if (strlen($title) >= 25) {
            return substr($title, 0, 25) . '...';
        } else {
            return $title;
        }
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
add_filter('the_title', 'short_product_titles_chars', 10, 2);
```

And this code works fine on the shop page, but it doesn't work if I use the "featured product" or the "recent products" widget om my start page.
How can I change this code so it even works with widgets?

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'product_excerpt', 35, 2);

function product_excerpt()
{
    $length = 30;
    global $post;
    $content = $post->post_excerpt;
    $wordarray = explode(' ', $content, $length + 1);
    if(count($wordarray) > $length) :
        array_pop($wordarray);
        array_push($wordarray, '...');
        $content = implode(' ', $wordarray);
        $content = force_balance_tags($content);
        $content = substr($content, 0, 30);
    endif;
   echo "<p>".$content."</p>";
}
```